# MySQL NOT NULL not working with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, null, create-table

I'm having an issue with my web pages accepting blank data from PHP forms and submitting them to my tables even though I have all columns in every table set as NOT NULL. Am I misunderstanding what NOT NULL means or did I do something else wrong (perhaps with the injection prevention)?

Here's how I have my table created:

```
CREATE TABLE USER(
user_ID int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username char(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_ID));
```

Here's the input page in case it matters:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='adduser.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='username'/>
<input type='submit'/>";
?>
```

Validation Page: (adduser.php)

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['username'];
$name=stripslashes($name);
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($name);
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO User VALUES ('','$name');")
echo "Entry successful";
else
echo "Invalid entry: ".mysql_error();
?>
```

The entry is successful no matter what I put in the text box. I'm new to SQL so what is this elementary mistake I'm making?

Comment: Btw, you don't need to make a primary key not null - it's done implicitly.

Comment: And what values does the `user_id` column take as a result?

Comment: A zero length string is not the same as NULL. The zero length string for user_id in the INSERT is being evaluated as integer value, which MySQL sees as 0, which triggers the AUTO_INCREMENT behavior on that  column. The zero length string is valid for the username column, so the insert succeeds. You may want to consider adding a UNIQUE KEY constraint on the user_name column, so you don't have two rows with the same user_name. (It's good to see the the real escape string function being used; it's not so good to the mysql_ interface being used when **PDO** and **mysqli** are available.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between NULL and an empty string ''. Character fields in the database that are set to NOT NULL will still accept an empty string. In this case the form is posting an empty string to your validation page and that is then getting inserted into the database.

Your validation page needs to check that the string is not empty before going ahead with the database insert.

Comment: OP may also want to add a unique constraint on user_name column; and consider using either **PDO** or **mysqli** instead of the deprecated mysql_ interface.